# How to use loop variable within string (name)

Tags: c++, loops, objective-c++

I am doing object oriented programming and I have to give different names (physBox1, physBox2..... physBox10) to 10 different boxes (represented by 10 element array `Box[10`]) in C++ language.

```
for (G4int i=0; i<10; i++) 
{
    new G4PVPlacement(0, Box[i],"phyBox[i]");
}
```

Here `G4PVPlacement` is some class which takes three values - second value is `Box[i]` indicating the 10 boxes and `physBox[i]` are names of that boxes. Here I am confused whether `physBox[i]` will be treated as a single string or here `[i]` can run from 0 to 9 according to "for loop".

Comment: What is preventing you from trying it out yourself?

Answer (score 5):

`"phyBox[i]"` is a string literal, within which `i` is simply the letter `i`. If you want to make a string containing a run-time value, you'll have to do it yourself:

```
"phyBox[" + std::to_string(i) + "]"
```